# Octave timestamp custom format

Tags: octave

I am getting this problem in Octave

```
datevec("24.02.2016 10:04:36","%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
DATE not parsed correctly with given format

datevec("24.02.2016 10:04:36","dd.mm.YY HH:MM:SS ")
DATE not parsed correctly with given format
```

How do I specify correctly my custom format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 4 digit year (i.e. `2016`) but you are using a 2 digit year formatting string i.e. `YY`).

You should do it like this:

```
datevec("24.02.2016 10:04:36","dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS")
```

Please read [the docs](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/datestr.html) to see how Octave likes it's date formatting strings.